# Make docker exit during dockerfile if errors in webpack

Tags: docker, webpack

i build an image for deployment on AWS in continuous deployment, the problem is that sometimes I have errors during webpack, and if that so the site is unavailable, how can I make docker exit during `Dockerfile` if there are errors during webpack?

Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ***

COPY . /src
COPY development.js /src/client/app/config/env
WORKDIR /src

RUN npm set progress=false 
RUN npm install --quiet node-sass@3.13.1
RUN npm install --quiet gifsicle@3.0.4
RUN npm install --quiet jpegtran-bin@3.2.0
RUN npm install --quiet optipng-bin@3.1.4
RUN npm install --quiet pngquant-bin@3.1.1
RUN npm install --quiet
ENV NODE_ENV __NODE_ENV__
RUN gulp webpack --display-error-details
RUN mkdir -p /src/dist/app/assets && mv /src/client/app/assets /src/dist/app

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: the response is --bail

Comment: You can answer your own question and mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is adding --bail next to webpack.